# convert string contains +GMT date to datetime object

Tags: asp.net

how convert string ="yyyyMMddHHmmss+GMT" to datetime

example string date="20130607000000+1000"

i need for that convertor

whats relation by this forme string and datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    date, "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: this solution not my question because date="yyyyMMddHHmmss+GMT"  and this code not marche and have an     error :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.